# Simple text editor with margin notes possibility

Tags: libreoffice

I am looking for text editor, as simple as it is possible, which will give me opportunity to make margin notes. Actually it's only requirement which I have. Currently I use LibreOffice Writer and I solve this problem by use frames as margin space but it is not as useful as I've expected. I mean that order of text in frame is quite strange, I am forced to resize text there in every every case and also creating frame always when I want to write.

Do you know some Ubuntu tool which can give me mentioned opportunity? Maybe some kind of online tool either?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`LibreOffice Writer` actually already has the feature you want. The marginal notes function in `Writer` is simple to use and doesn't require any creation of frames, resizing text, or changing the actual body of the document, so I should experiment with that again as it is ideal for annotating all types of document.

You place your cursor where you want the comment bubble to emerge from (see screenshot below) and either use Insert > Comment or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and the comment bubble appears in the margin.

As you can see in the screenshot below, you can have multiple comments and you can use the feature with any other kind of document such as `.txt`, but you would have to save it as `.odt` to retain the notes. If using the `.doc` format, the margin notes will be saved successfully, but use of `.odt` is always recommended if possible.

If you want to prevent the comments from displaying go to view > comments and make sure comments is unchecked. When the cursor is inside a comment box in the margin, enter <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>PgUp</kbd> to move to the previous comment, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>PgDown</kbd> to move to the next one.

More information on the comment feature is available at [the official site](http://help.libreoffice.org/Common/Comment_1). Full documentation on `LibreOffice` and its programs such as `Writer` are available in pdf format from [this site](http://wiki.documentfoundation.org/Documentation/Publications).

I am reluctant to recommend another text editor, because when `LibreOffice` is used with the special comment feature it should actually be what you need for normal plain text documents as well as office documents.

[image]

Comment: I am compelled to comment - smashing answer!